# How to view a plain text file created in Linux in Drive app?

Tags: google-drive

I created a small plain text file (in utf-8 encoding) in Ubuntu and then uploaded to Drive.In my Android phone, I open Drive app, and want to view the text file, but it says "No preview available" and asks me to download it. How can I preview the text file without downloading it?

Comment: Have you tried uploading a file with `.txt` extension and preview it in Drive app? Drive may be geared to preview files based on extension and not on mime-type.

Comment: In Drive, I added ".txt" to the file name, but it is still not previewable.